# Share same KeepassXC on multiple devices

Tags: ftp, keepass

Is there a way to share the same Keepass database on multiple devices?

I've heard that it can be done with an FTP server, but I am not sure how to set it up or if it even is the best option?

I have an Ubuntu VM that I would like to host the database on (my own physical server).

That means when I make a new username password on my laptop it will automatically do it on my phone as well.

Comment: For Keepass, I just copy the main DB to each computer that has Keepass installed. Works fine.

Comment: @John Yeah it works, but when a laptop user changes a password, it has to be changed on the phone as well. Shouldn't there be an easier way than doing everything manually?

Comment: You could keep a copy of the Keepass DB on the iPhone user's iCloud.  The key thing with Keepass is to have one owner of the main DB and then distribute it to others. I like and use Keypass, but LastPass might serve your purpose better.

Answer (score 3):

You can share the same Keepass database among multiple devices, but not directly within KeepassXC. The database is just a regular file that will need to be synced between the multiple devices through other means. I am currently syncing between several Linux computers and Android devices. I keep the file in sync by using a Nextcloud (https://www.nextcloud.com) server. You can do the same thing using Dropbox, Google Drive, Microsoft OneDrive, or any other service that lets you keep files synchronized between multiple devices. I have used Dropbox in the past. The Keepass app that I use on Android (Keepass2Android) natively supports several such services.

Comment: Great! Do you know how to do it on a server, that you own by yourself?

Comment: There are a number of ways to do it. I'm going to assume that you are running KeepassXC on a Linux laptop and Keepass2Android on the phone. A solution that doesn't involve a lot of additional server setup would be to use sshfs on the laptop and use an SFTP connection in Keepass2Android. I've not tried that exact combination, but would expect it to work. You could also run your own Nextcloud on your server or set up Webdav. Most any kind of network file system should work.

Comment: The [iOS app strongbox](https://strongboxsafe.com/) can handle `sftp` in free tier version.

Answer (score 0):

For sharing only between Apple devices, by far the easiest method is to put the database files on iCloud and download the [Strongbox app for iPhone](https://strongboxsafe.com/).  That works flawlessly and is easy to set up.

To add non-Apple devices to the sharing group, Mike Cowper's answer is probably the easiest (use Dropbox, OneDrive, or Google Drive instead of iCloud).  But I'll mention one quite technical solution that is explained [here](https://janikvonrotz.ch/2021/08/31/sync-obsidian-mobile-app-with-working-copy-git-repo/); it essentially uses three Git repositories: one on iCloud, one on Github (or some other host), and one on your Linux VM. The repository on the iPhone is controlled by an excellent app called [Working Copy](https://workingcopyapp.com), which costs $25.  You have to push and pull changes for them to sync, and some people won't like taking the extra trouble.

The article is about syncing Obsidian files (a note-taking program), but everything is exactly the same for any type of files, and the method lets you keep your database on iCloud so you don't lose the smooth, trouble-free sharing across your Apple devices.  To add another non-Apple machine, you would just set up a git repo on it and link to the Github repo.