# Can I use the Google Authenticator (OTP) app on my PC?

Tags: two-factor-authentication, windows-authentication, google-authenticator, multi-factor-authentication

Sometimes it can be a little annoying to check the mobile app to access a regular website. Is it possible to use an OTP authenticator app that can be used on both mobile and PC?

Comment: Search for `OTP Authentication Windows App` and you'll find apps, even at least one on the Microsoft Store (I'm assuming you run windows)

Comment: I would try using Windows Subsystem for Android to run the application, or just run, one of the many OTP applications that exist

Comment: Unless you get Android apps working on Windows

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: Authy desktop will reach EOL at [19th March 2024](https://help.twilio.com/articles/19753631228315). So it's no longer a viable option. Out of other available apps with TOTP support, [KeePassXC](https://keepassxc.org/) is a good cross-platform and open source alternative.

It allows you to assign OTP to each entry, by right clicking on it and choosing **TOTP** -> **Set up TOTP...**. [Detailed guide.](https://keepassxc.org/docs/KeePassXC_UserGuide#_adding_totp_to_an_entry)

The disadvantage compared to Authy is that it's a local app rather than a web service, so you'll need to use external tools to sync the added entries using external tools. See e.g. this question: [Share same KeepassXC on multiple devices](https://superuser.com/questions/1626205/share-same-keepassxc-on-multiple-devices) for more info.

As for more similar alternatives that work more like cross-device services, there are few paid ones, I couldn't find anything free.

---

Google Authenticator has no PC version(s).

[Authy](https://authy.com/) is an example of an app which works on all commonly used systems. It can synchronize all accounts with password encrypted backups.

You can download it for Windows [here](https://authy.com/download/).

Comment: Authy desktop will be retired in August 2024  - https://help.twilio.com/articles/19753631228315-Authy-for-Desktop-End-of-Life-EOL-

Comment: But wait.... Twilio has now decided to TERMINATE Authy desktop on March 19th, 2024.  So, don't bother with Authy...   Or if you did, GOOD LUCK!    UGH.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Google Authenticator uses the standard OATH TOTP protocol. As long as you still have the original key or Qr code (issued by the website) from when the app was set up, you can import that PSK into any OATH TOTP-compatible desktop app. Several exist for Windows.

Comment: [KeePassXC](https://keepassxc.org/docs/KeePassXC_UserGuide#_adding_totp_to_an_entry) has this feature. From the documentation: _right-click the desired entry, choose TOTP → Set up TOTP, paste the secret code. You will see a clock icon in that entry’s row and have the ability to reveal the current code_

Comment: Interesting approach!   Just takes the discipline of setting up the multiple authenticator apps all at the same time.